# React router v6, I'm struggling to understand

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Okay, So I have a problem when trying to use react router dom.

So this is my App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./screens/Home";
import FixedBar from "./components/fixedBar/FixedBar";
import Hamburger from "./components/hamburger/Hamburger";
import Header from "./components/header/Header";
function App() {
  const [toggleHamburger, setToggleHamburger] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Header
       toggleHamburger={toggleHamburger}
       setToggleHamburger={setToggleHamburger}
     />
     <Hamburger show={toggleHamburger} />
     <FixedBar />
     <Routes>
       <Route
         path="/"
         element={
           <Home
             toggleHamburger={toggleHamburger}
             setToggleHamburger={setToggleHamburger}
           />
         }
       />
     </Routes>
   </div>
 );} export default App;
```

and this is my Home.js

```
import "../App.css";
import Info from "../components/info/Info";
import Women from "../components/women/Women";
import Men from "../components/men/Men";
import Contact from "../components/contact/Contact";

function Home({ toggleHamburger, setToggleHamburger }) {
  return (
    <div className="Home">
      <Info click={() => setToggleHamburger(false)} />
      <Women click={() => setToggleHamburger(false)} />
      <Men click={() => setToggleHamburger(false)} />
      <Contact click={() => setToggleHamburger(false)} />
    </div>
  );
} export default Home;
```

and the problem I am getting is (as you can see the page is blank) :

[image]

maybe you guys know what the problem is?

Comment: The error is saying that `React` is null for some reason. See this [line of code](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v6.3.0/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L151) in source, `let historyRef = React.useRef<BrowserHistory>();`. Can you update your post to share your package.json file, the component rendering the `BrowserRouter`, and how you are running your app?

Comment: Hi drew thanks for your answer. The thing is when i just call <Home /> it renders the page. But when i try to use the route it wont for some reason.

Comment: Ok, and we'd need to see a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] to have any more context as to why there may be an issue.

Comment: drew thank you so much you just made me realize what the problem is lol. apparently I forgot to cd to the client folder and installed react-router-dom at the wrong place.

Comment: Ok, cool. Glad to help. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers and good luck!